# cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies with --lib flag on Windows

Tags: haskell, package, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

Using PowerShell (Admin) to install the package *parallel* I tried to do :
`cabal install parallel`
which finished with

```
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
Warning:
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: Installation might not be completed as desired! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The command "cabal install [TARGETS]" doesn't expose libraries.
* You might have wanted to add them as dependencies to your package. In this
case add "parallel" to the build-depends field(s) of your package's .cabal
file.
* You might have wanted to add them to a GHC environment. In this case use
"cabal install --lib parallel". The "--lib" flag is provisional: see
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6481 for more information.
```

Then I tried with the `--lib` flag and here's what I get :

```
cabal install --lib parallel
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: binary-0.8.9.0/installed-0.8.9.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: bytestring (user goal)
[__1] rejecting: bytestring-0.11.2.0 (constraint from user target requires
==0.11.1.0)
[__1] trying: bytestring-0.11.1.0/installed-0.11.1.0
[__2] next goal: deepseq (user goal)
[__2] rejecting: deepseq-1.4.6.1 (conflict: bytestring =>
deepseq==1.4.6.0/installed-1.4.6.0)
[__2] rejecting: deepseq-1.4.5.0, deepseq-1.4.4.0, deepseq-1.4.3.0,
deepseq-1.4.2.0, deepseq-1.4.1.2, deepseq-1.4.1.1, deepseq-1.4.1.0,
deepseq-1.4.0.0, deepseq-1.3.0.2, deepseq-1.3.0.1, deepseq-1.3.0.0,
deepseq-1.2.0.1, deepseq-1.2.0.0, deepseq-1.1.0.2, deepseq-1.1.0.1,
deepseq-1.1.0.0, deepseq-1.0.0.0, deepseq-1.4.6.0/installed-1.4.6.0,
deepseq-1.4.6.0 (constraint from user target requires ==1.4.6.1)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: bytestring, deepseq)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: binary, deepseq, bytestring, ghc,
unbuildable
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

The `--minimize-conflict-set` give me this :

```
cabal install --lib --minimize-conflict-set parallel
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: deepseq-1.4.6.1 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: ghc (user goal)
[__1] rejecting: ghc-9.2.1/installed-9.2.1 (conflict: deepseq==1.4.6.1, ghc =>
deepseq==1.4.6.0/installed-1.4.6.0)
[__1] trying: ghc-9.2.1
[__2] unknown package: unbuildable (dependency of ghc)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: ghc, unbuildable)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: deepseq, ghc, unbuildable
```

I precise that I've done `cabal update` already and I'm using `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.1`.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Same problem but for HUnit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some packages just forgot to update their upper version bounds. Add `--allow-newer` to the command line and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
Here's what I get with it : 
```cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: deepseq-1.4.6.1 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: ghc (user goal)
[__1] rejecting: ghc-9.2.1/installed-9.2.1 (conflict: deepseq==1.4.6.1, ghc =>
deepseq==1.4.6.0/installed-1.4.6.0)
[__1] trying: ghc-9.2.1
[__2] unknown package: unbuildable (dependency of ghc)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: ghc, unbuildable)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: deepseq, ghc, unbuildable```